# Is there a way to change SSID password without affecting all connected devices?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, passwords, ssid

I feel that my Wifi password is compromised, but I have 37 devices connected to the SSID currently.

Is it possible to change the SSID password in the router without changing it in all 37 devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SSID is an identifier and does not have a password. Your Wireless Access DOES have a password.

If you believe your wireless has been compromised, you should change the password.

However, that will affect ALL devices. There is not any way around this.

Even if you change the SSID name, that will also affect all devices.  (Something I just did here with a change in wireless router). This is true for the routers I have used here and at my small business clients.

Comment: If you change password in a same type (like WPA to WPA) and  ssid then it will not disrupt the devices. Older routers kept track of MAC address, but some new and updated firmware keeps track of SSIDs to prevent disruption. So keeping the firmware updated is a good thing.

Comment: In a normal modern router, if you change the SSID, the devices have to change as well. I noted my experience in this above.

Comment: It depends on which kind of router you are using. Only very few routers offer this functionality.